# Run expand on find results

Tags: linux, unix, find, expand, xargs

I'm trying to run the expand shell command on all files found by a `find` command. I've tried -exec and xargs but both failed. Can anyone explain me why? I'm on a mac for the record.

---

`find . -name "*.php" -exec expand -t 4 {} > {} \;`

This just creates a file `{}` with all the output instead of overwriting each individual found file itself.

---

`find . -name "*.php" -print0 | xargs -0 -I expand -t 4 {} > {}`

And this just outputs

```
4 {}
xargs: 4: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your command does not work for two reasons.

1. The output redirection is done by the shell and not by `find`. That means that the shell will redirect `find`s output into the file `{}`.
2. The redirection would occur immediately. That means that the file will be written even before it is read by the `expand` command. So it's not possible to redirect a command's output into the input file.

Unfortunately `expand` doesn't allow to write it's output into a file. So you have to use output redirection. If you use `bash` you could define a `function` that executes `expand`, redirects the output into a temporary file and move the temporary file back over the original file. The problem is that `find` will run a new shell to execute the `expand` command.

But there is a solution:

```
expand_func () {
  expand -t 4 "$1" > "$1.tmp"
  mv "$1.tmp" "$1"
}

export -f expand_func

find . -name \*.php -exec bash -c 'expand_func {}' \;
```

You are exporting the function `expand_func` to sub shells using `export -f`. And you don't execute `expand` itself using `find -exec` but you execute a new `bash` that executes the exported `expand_func`.

Answer (score 1):

'expand' isn't really worth the trouble.
You can just use sed instead:

```
find . -name "*.php" | xargs sed -i -e 's/\t/    /g'
```